# Unable to set set max_clause_count on ElastiSearch 2.4.5

Tags: magento2, search

I have set elasticsearch on Magento 2 Enterprise Edition. On trying to load categories page, I get these error:

(Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\ServerErrorResponseException): too_many_clauses: maxClauseCount is set to 1024

When I try to update elasticsearch.yaml to index.query.bool.max_clause_count: 10024 as suggested here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-overview.html elasticsearch does not start.

I have read that setting maxClauseCount has been deprecated in Elasticsearch 5 https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/breaking_50_settings_changes.html#_search_settings. But I am using version 2.4.5

How do I go about setting maxClauseCount?